# Did the Borg Queen order the Voyager/Borg alliance?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, borg

Is there any evidence the Borg Queen was the one who agreed to the alliance between Voyager and the Borg against Species 8472?

The Borg were acting their usual selves when Janeway approached them with the idea of working together, then suddenly changed their minds and agreed.

Was this due to the Queen countermanding the Collective’s judgment on the situation, like she did later in *Endgame, Part 1* when Voyager enters the transwarp hub nebula and the Collective feels the need to assimilate them?

Comment: No. The Queen *is* the Borg and the Borg are the queen.

Comment: There's evidence of the queen counter comanding the collectives judgement when voyager enters the transwarp hub nebula and the collective fells the need to assimilate  is warranted the queen commanded the collective to let them continue , endgame part 1

Comment: There is a possibility... the Borg Queen did admit to 7of9 in Dark Frontier that she masterminded her release to Janeway and her crew. No reason to presume she was not involved with the idea of an alliance to further her 7of9 infiltration goals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Janeway approached The Borg with a game plan from the beginning. There's no mention of the Borg Queen influencing any decision making here. I think the decision was pretty obvious, The Doctor had found a way to reprogram Borg to avoid detection by Species 8472, essentially giving them a way to survive.

Once the alliance was over, the Borg failed in attempting to assimilate the crew of the Voyager. So it seems this was a collective decision based on their needs of survival, which makes sense, since that's really what the Borg is all about.

Comment: You would think an Alarm would go off in  her unicomplex chambers alerting her of the situation the minute they were made aware of potential technology to beat species 8472 then she took over the situation, an alarm went off when the tactical cube was under attack by voyager then she took controle of the  cube. Unimatrix zero part1

Comment: Well, you'd think so. But what canonically happened, and what _we_ can say happened are two completely different things.

Answer (score 5):

## It wasn't a sudden change of mind.  The Borg demanded the technology without guaranteeing safe passage before finally relenting.  Also, the Queen and the Collective are indistinguishable.

Here is the exact dialogue from the episode **["Scorpion"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpion_(episode))**:

> **JANEWAY:** Open a channel.
>
> **BORG:** We are the Borg. You will be assimilated. Resistance is futile.
>
> **TUVOK:** They've locked onto us with a tractor beam.
>
> **JANEWAY:** Borg vessel, this is Captain Janeway of the starship Voyager. I have tactical information about Species 8472. I want to negotiate.
>
> **BORG:** Negotiation is irrelevant. You will be assimilated.
>
> **JANEWAY:** Borg vessel. What you're receiving is a sample of the knowledge we possess. If you don't disengage your tractor beam immediately, I will have that data destroyed. You have ten seconds to comply. We know you're in danger of being defeated. you can't afford to risk losing this information. Disengage your tractor 
>   *(Janeway is beamed away.)*
>
> [Borg Cube]
>
> **BORG:** State your demands.
>
> **JANEWAY:** I want safe passage through your space. Once my ship is beyond Borg territory, I'll give you our research.
>
> **BORG [OC]:** Unacceptable. Our space is vast. ***Your passage would require too much time. We need the technology now.***
>
> **JANEWAY:** If I give it to you now, you'll assimilate us.
>
> **BORG:** ***Species 8472 must be stopped. Our survival is your survival. Give us the technology.***
>
> **JANEWAY:** No. Safe passage first or no deal.

From this, I would not describe it as a "sudden change" of mind on the Borg's part.  Janeway knew she would be able to negotiate with the Borg because she had something they desperately needed.  Even then, the Borg tried to "have their cake and eat it too" by demanding the technology without guaranteeing safe passage, but Janeway refused and the Borg relented.

As for the Queen, recall from *First Contact* that she and the Collective cannot be distinguished.  She is simply an avatar for the entire Collective.

> **BORG QUEEN:** I am the beginning. The end. The one who is many. I am the Borg.

Her decisions and influence cannot be thought of as separate from those of the Collective.

Comment: They can be distinguished since we have seen the queen counter command the collectives judgement before

Comment: @Darren : That could simply be an outward representation of a decision process made by the Collective.  Part of the role of the Queen is to create the illusion of an individual when dealing with high-profile assimilation candidates like Picard, Data, or Seven.

Comment: Could've been a `WHILE` loop that eventually fell on the correct answer ;)

Comment: @JohnBell : Hehe, indeed.

Comment: Yes but there has been times when we have seen the queen alone in the unicomplex chambers for example unimatrix zero and dealing with that issue what would the collective need an illusion of an individual for when they could just deal with the problem collectively, the queen has control over the hive mind and can change its judgment of needed

Comment: @Darren : I suspect there are a lot of Bayesian statistical processes that run in tandem when the Borg try to make a "decision".  There is probably a baseline course of action dictated by experience, such as assimilation of a new species, but new information acquired about a particular encounter can override the baseline action with a "better" one.  It could be that the Queen always vocalizes these shifts in the statistics, whether an audience is present or not.  But I suspect these processes run even if she is dismantled and tucked away somewhere.

Comment: That's a good theory

Comment: @Darren humans also have an internal voice in our head - that internal voice can change a health persons mind. How many times have you said I'm going to do something 100% and then your inner voice say 'nah maybe some other time'. You can think of it the same way the queen is like your inner voice whereas the Borg are the normal outwards everyday thinking, the queen as the inner voice says 'actually its not worth the trouble" sometimes